# Нахождение цикла в LinkedList

Tags: python, алгоритм, односвязный-список

StackOwerflow, есть такая проблема:
Начал изучать LinkedList и метод нахождения  циклов, а именно: List Reversin (реверсирование списка). В книге по которой я учу алгоритмы(Стивенс) написано следущее: Если сохранить какое-то уникальное значение для первой ячейки, потом реверсировать список 2 раза, далее сравнить новое значение первой ячейки и если они окажутся равны - значит в списке цикла нет. Но вот как-то нет, скорее всего я неправильно делаю реверс списка(хотя как в книжке) Вот код:

```
import uuid

class Cell:
    def __init__(self, prev, curr, nex):
        self.this = curr
        self.next = nex
        self.prev = prev
        self.ref = None


class CellList:
def __init__(self, cells):
    self.cells = []
    self.starts = None
    if len(cells):
        for i in range(len(cells)):
            if i == 0:
                self.add_cell(None, cells[i], None)
            else:
                self.add_cell(self.cells[i - 1], cells[i], None)
                self.cells[i - 1].next = self.cells[i]
        self.starts = self.cells[0]
        self.starts.ref = uuid.uuid4()

    def walk(self):
    i = self.starts
    while 1:
        yield i.this
        if i.next == None:
            break
        i = i.next

def add_cell(self, prev, curr, nex):
    self.cells.append(Cell(prev, curr, nex))
    def add_cycle(self, index1, index2):
    self.cells[index1].next = self.cells[index2]

def reverse_list(self):
    prev = None
    this = self.starts
    while 1:
        next = this.next
        this.next = prev
        prev = this
        this = next
        try:
            this.next
        except AttributeError:
            self.starts = prev
            if not self.starts.ref:
                self.starts.ref = uuid.uuid4()
            return prev

def has_cycles(self):
    if not len(self.cells):
        return False
    sentinel = self.starts.ref
    print(sentinel)
    self.reverse_list()
    self.reverse_list()
    new_sentinel = self.starts.ref
    print(new_sentinel)
    if sentinel == new_sentinel:
        return False
    return True

a = CellList([4, 2, 6, 3, 4, 7, 2, 9, 0, 2])
print([i for i in a.walk()])
a.add_cycle(-1, 3)
print(a.has_cycles())
```

Comment: Что конкретно будет являться циклом в вашем понимании? Двойной полный проход туда-сюда как-то кажется "слегка тяжеловат" для какой бы то ни было задачи. Попробуйте формально и максимально четко сформулировать, какая конкретно ситуация будет называться циклом и, возможно, необходимость в двойном реверсе отпадет.

Comment: Если список односвязный и закручен на конце, вы никогда не вернётесь даже в первом проходе. Двусвязный список закольцевать в принципе нельзя.

Comment: Поправка ко второму тезису. Можно, но это будет классический закольцованный двусвязный список и его не надо снова-таки проверять на закольцованность (если правильно задизайнить). Смотрите, например, как я его применил для простой задачи: https://pastebin.com/mScMkkdy